# AWS Code pipeline failing - The runtime parameter of nodejs12.x is no longer supported - aws serverless lamda .net

Tags: node.js, .net, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-codepipeline

We are using aws serverless cloud formation framework with .net 6.0 and aws Lamda. And we are using aws code pipeline for build and deployment. Suddenly it gives "The runtime parameter of nodejs12.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs18.x) while creating or updating functions." error in sls deploy stage. We are using the following commands in our yml file

- npm install -g serverless@3.28.1
- npm install serverless-plugin-warmup@4.9.0 --save-dev
- npm install serverless-api-gateway-caching@1.9.0
- npm install serverless-plugin-split-stacks@1.12.0
- npm install --save-dev serverless-prune-plugin@2.0.2
- npm install --save-dev serverless-step-functions@3.13.0

We tried to upgrade to the latest serverless version and also the above plugins. But in that case, also it fails without giving a specific error. Any suggestion to overcome this issue